# Which rdf files to load to recreate main DBpedia sparql endpoint locally?

Tags: dbpedia, databus

I have spun the local instance of DBpedia using docker images at https://github.com/dbpedia/virtuoso-sparql-endpoint-quickstart and loading https://databus.dbpedia.org/dbpedia/collections/latest-core hoping I could reproduce the main DBpedia SPARQL endpoint locally.

I understood from the documentation that this is the collection that is loaded to the main endpoint.

However the total number of triples is different (808587892 locally and 1104129087 on the main endpoint) and I'm not finding a single `dbo:wikiPageWikiLink` relation locally, while there are 240388379 in the main endpoint.

I'd really appreciate some pointers as to how to debug this or information on which files to load to virtuoso to have `dbo:wikiPageWikiLink`relations available - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have just received an answer to this question here: https://github.com/dbpedia/databus-maven-plugin/issues/150